# How do i access specific array item searching by a name and draw it using d3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, d3.js, graph

## Note :

First time i took all my data from a single JSON to test the output and if the json format is valid , now i want to take all the data from an array , i wrote down more details.

I have in each item of an array a JSON like this :

```
{
    "nodes":[
    {"id": "Name","group": 0},
    {
          "id": "Parent",
          "label": "Parent",
          "group" : 1
          }],
"links":[{
         "source": "Name",
         "target": "Parent"     
         }
]
     }
```

Keep in mind that there are more nodes and links in each item of the array .
I want to have a dropdownlist with all the names of the JSONS and when i select them and submit i want to display the graph from that particular entry.
The graph/JSON2 is the large .txt file from where i took all the recordings and saved them in an array.

**Index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  font: 9px helvetica;
}
#Help {
  float:right;
  

  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.ui-widget{
  float: right;

}


</style>
<body>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>
<script>

    

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("JSON2.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group);
  
  node.append("text")
      .attr("class","nodes")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id })
      .style("stroke", "gray");

       })



     

      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));


  node.on("click", function() {
      alert(function(d){return d.Statement})
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });
  



  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
<div class="ui-widget">
<button onclick=" LoadArray()">Load</button>
   <input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id="browsers">
        
      </datalist>
      <input type="submit" >
    <a href="https://www.google.ro/">
    <img id = "Help" src="Help.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
<script src="JSON2.txt"></script>
<form>  

</form>

    
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadArray() {
console.log("start");
for(var i = 0; i < DataArray.length; i++){
    console.log(i + " = " + DataArray[i]);
}
console.log(DataArray);
console.log("end");}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
```

I want to take each JSON from the array and .append it's first id or label(that's is the name of the json , the first id from the index .The one with the `group:0`) in the dropdown list and when i select and submit the graph should draw it's self with the nodes and links from the array.

Comment: If you want to update a graph for different json files, you will need to use a general update pattern such as the one used here https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern/

Comment: @ofey Thank you , i find it helpful , still need to do some digging

Comment: Bostock has a great example for updating data https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var ok = [{
    "nodes":[
    {"id": "Name","group": 0},
    {
          "id": "Parent",
          "label": "Parent",
          "group" : 1
          }],
"links":[{
         "source": "Name",
         "target": "Parent"     
         }
]
     },
 {
    "nodes":[
    {"id": "Name","group": 0},
    {
          "id": "Parent",
          "label": "Parent",
          "group" : 1
          }],
"links":[{
         "source": "Name",
         "target": "Parent"     
         }
]
     }    
     ]
     
ok.forEach(function(d,i){
//using each item
d.nodes.forEach(function(d,i){
console.log(d.id)
//do some thing
})

d.links.forEach(function(d,i){
console.log(d.source)
//do some thing
})
//or
//using the array  as data
//select.data(function(d,i) {return d.links})
//select.data(function(d,i) {return d.nodes})
})
```

Comment: Thank you , that was really helpful , now i need to figure out how to append in the option section each id .